# Altium->Coupled Inductors

Tags: transformer, simulation, altium, flyback, ac-dc

Im glad to be with you. I have question about coupled inductors in altium. I want to make a flyback converter and tried first as in Image 1 [image: Image 1- Circuit] . I converted 310V DC to 12V DC as you can see.[image: Image 2-Sim] I wrote spice model for T1(Transformer)
[image]
Then, I wanted to ascend my outputs as you see in the Image 4[image: Image 3 -Circuit]
But sim out came like in Image 5[image: Image4-Sim]
For 3 output transformer spice code that I wrote 
[image]

What is wrong?. I think 3 output transformer spice model wrong. But I didnt figure out. Give me advice please about that.

With my best regards...

Comment: Ddid spice give any warnings or errors?

Comment: You need to couple all pairs of inducturs, `K4 L2 L3 0.99`,  `K5 L2 L4 0.99`, etc. LTSpice lets you just do `Kx L1 L2 L3 L4 0.99`, but Altium's SPICE might not do that (I don't know).

Comment: "Ddid spice give any warnings or errors?"

@stark  No, I I didnt take any error about spice models.

Comment: @ThePhoton I added as you said 
'K4 L2 L3 0.99
K5 L2 L4 0.99
K6 L3 L4 0.99' and I take 12V. So thank you .
But Additionaly I made all grounds -> GND .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What is wrong?*

You've made the beginner's error of not understanding the importance of dot-notation when implementing a flyback transformer design. In your first circuit you have, in effect, got lucky with the right output voltage but it's not acting as a flyback converter but more like a regular forward converter and using the transformer as a regular step-down device.

This is not how flyback designs work.

[image]

The lower picture shows how I've altered the secondary coil to suit it working as a flyback converter. Flyback converters work by charging the primary coil and reverse biasing the secondary diode then, turning off the primary MOSFET so that "fly-back" occurs and the energy stored in the transformer's magnetic field is released and forward biases the diode. It's a two-phase operation.

Correct use of transformer secondary phase relative to primary phase: -

[image]

Notice the change in the position of the dot on the secondary - you can keep the dot as per your original diagram but you then need to connect the secondary diode to the non-dotted end of the secondary (as shown in my amendment to your original diagram).

Picture from [A Guide to Flyback Transformers by CoilCraft](https://www.coilcraft.com/edu/flyback_transformer.cfm).

Other reading: [Mean Well - Flyback converter](https://www.meanwelldirect.co.uk/glossary/what-is-a-flyback-converter/): -

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very helpful . I understand what  flyback transformer means more. I tried my first circuit as you said before. And it worked again but more true:) . But even  I change my 3 outputs transformer seconder's dots so their polarities, I didnt take good results. Is spice model wrong?

Comment: If your model intends to have a primary to secondary turns ratio of about 45:1 with a coupling of 0.99 then it doesn't look wrong to me. It's very easy to get into a mess with flyback converters and using the zeners on the output(s) is usually a sign of trying to fix something the wrong way. Flyback converters do not require zener diodes on their outputs but they do require absolute critical management of the duty cycle.

Comment: Virtually every spice design I have seen uses separate inductors coupled with "k" components. In micro-cap (my sim tool) when you ad a "k" you specify the inductor names that are coupled and the global coupling factor. Maybe try doing it that way BUT get the simple circuit working correctly WITHOUT the zener then, move on to the multi-secondary version.

Comment: As I searched from the internet I calculated V1/V2 = 310/12 == 25.8 and inductance ratio  (N1/N2)^2 =(L1/L2)  so 25.8^2 = 667.3 so I gave for my first circuit sec inductance 2uH(random) then for 667.3*2 =~ 1.3m . And it was true as we understand from sim. But for 3 output transformer I gave 1.3*3 = 3.9m to primer and sec's stayed same 2uH. Coupling factors 0.99 for both circuits.

Comment: I tried my circuits either altium sim or ltspice , First circuit worked, but 3 output didnt.

Comment: Increasing the primary from 1.3 mH to 3.9 mH - why did you do that - what were your reasons?

Comment: I thought one output 1.3,  three outputs 3.9mH. But true was 1.3mH. I took finally 12V DC. But in Altium doesn't allow more than one GND. Even I choose GND as a reference ground, sim is being broken.

Comment: OK so 1.3 mH worked yes?

Comment: Yes @Andy aka. Thank you for answers.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you are having with Altium regards multiple grounds - is this part of the question?

Comment: If you are done with this Q and A, please consider formally accepting the answer to close it off @GuneyBoss

Comment: My main question was actually Is transformer's spice model true or wrong? I understood that is wrong. By trying K5, K6 and k7 which are seconders coupling factors in addition to K1,K2 and K3. I will use them in power supply . But those outputs must will be different grounds apart from input. When I tried with multiple ground(Total =4 ==> 1 to input , 3 to outputs such as out1's out1_gnd , out2's out2_gnd and out3's out4_gnd) simulation gave me wrong results again. Finally I found true spice model but, now I have multiple ground problem.